# How do i setup Slack Notifications for Gitlab scheduled pipelines only?

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, devops, continuous-deployment

I want to be notified via slack whether my scheduled pipeline runs are failing or passing. I also do not want a trigger every time the pipeline fails or passes, I want it to be specifically limited to the scheduled pipelines